# macOS icon suddenly appeared on desktop and can't remove (Ventura)

Tags: macos, icon, desktop

See attached photo. The macOS volume has appeared as an icon on my desktop. I can't seem to remove it, and wonder why it has appeared. It doesn't appear to be an alias/shortcut.

If I go into finder this item is not listed under 'Desktop', nor is it listed if I use the command line to list items in the Desktop folder.

Ventura 13.3 on Macbook Pro. I've been having some issues with spotlight and searching using finder, so maybe it's related.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the Desktop Wallpaper (beside the icon or elsewhere) to bring Finder into keyboard focus, then activate the shortcut  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>  Command comma for prefs[settings].

[image: Finder Settings on macOS 13.3]

- Uncheck all items you don't want to see displayed on the Desktop.
- On a system that's able to save these preferences correctly, the Desktop should update promptly.

As far as the system is concerned though, these are "real" & not just aliases, so don't try deleting or throwing away [not that it will actually let you] though for removable drives,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>E</kbd>  will eject them, same as any other method.

Comment: thanks. this resolved the issue. I do not understand why this appeared, but most likely a bug given I've been having issues with finder indexing and search.